# Is there anything that allows me to smoothly zoom in with a trackpad

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, zooming

I've googled to hell and back about this and I cannot find any information.

Is there

- A browser
- An Extension
- Any program

That allows me to smoothly zoom a Webpage with a pinching gesture on my trackpad? My laptop supports multitouch and I have a bunch of programs that emulate most touchpad gestures, I just can't believe there wouldn't be a single way to get a smooth zoom pinch on Ubuntu.

I'm not looking to bind <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to a pinch gesture on my trackpad to be completely clear.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

If you use Firefox (recommended) which comes pre-installed with Ubuntu and its the default browser, I class it as the native browser as I have never used anything else on Ubuntu, the latest and fastest version (atow) is Firefox Quantum v70 and if you add the following extension this gives you the ability to zoom smoothly using the trackpad and I think this is exactly what you need:)

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-touch-zoom/

Alternatively you can zoom using the keys on the keyboard or the mouse and the advantage of these is they work with all applications and do not require any additional apps or plug-ins .  I myself don't like using the trackpad at all and if I want to zoom I use either the keys CTR plus "+" and CTR plus "-" to zoom in and out, or alternatively I have a wireless mouse in which case I can zoom using the middle-mouse button while pressing and holding CTRL.

[edited] Removed this alternative as I realised it was in fact the other answer.

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work with pinch, although it does kind of work with shift + scroll, although it's quite clunky.

Comment: I'm unsure what you're talking about. You mean just pressing CTRL and scrolling up and down on Linux? That just uses the default browser zoom which breaks how the page looks.

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean either! As I understand you are looking for "anything that allows you to smoothly zoom using the trackpad!   I just realised that the alternative I added is exactly what Wojciech suggested in the other answer so have removed it as an alternative in my answer, Wojciech's answer was voted down but it worked and to me and given the browser plug-in didn't work its the best method involving the trackpad.  I tried it using various apps and FF using google maps and it works as good as the keyboard and mouse options and it works everywhere.

Comment: I'm trying to say that using ctrl and scrolling isn't smooth at all, it's the same as pressing ctrl + or ctrl -

Comment: Ok got ya.   Currently out of the box there are no trackpad sensitivity options or support for the full range of gestures, including the basic two finger pinch along with some degree of sensitivity controls.  I was looking through enhancement requests on Bugzilla from some years back on the subject and found that trackpad controls are not just lacking in Ubuntu but other OS's also don't provide this level of control and its because the hardware manufacturer only ever provided the most basic functions and any enhancements have come not from the manufacturer but from enthusiasts/developers.

Answer (score 0):

This extension doesn't enable pinch-to-zoom but it's the same functionality nonetheless, by using Shift + 2 finger-swipe gesture.

Here are the steps to enable this functionality:

- Download this:
  https://github.com/NayamAmarshe/firefox-multi-touch-zoom/archive/refs/heads/master.zip
- Extract the zip file somewhere.
- Open your Chromium-based browser and go to the extensions page.
- Turn on Developer Mode
- Press 'Load Unpacked' button.
- Find the folder where you extracted the zip file, it should have an
  'extension' folder, select that.
- The extension will now show up in the list. Use Shift + 2-finger-swipe up/down to use smooth-zooming.

Answer (score -1):

You can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and move two fingers up or down to zoom out or zoom in.

Comment: This is the same as doing ctrl + so not really what I'm looking for